# Error "Cast string to float is not supported" on training a binary classifier Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a binary classifier using neural networks but when I try to start the training, but I get this error:

> UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
> [[node binary_crossentropy/Cast (defined at :7) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_963]
>
> Function call stack:
> train_function

This is the function that I am using to create the Neural Network:

```
def build_model_1():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(neuronas, activation='relu', input_shape=[size]),
    layers.Dense(neuronas, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(neuronas, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(neuronas, activation='softmax'),
    layers.Dense(2)
  ])
  model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

neuronas = 32
model_1 = build_model_1()
model_1.summary()
```

To obtain the sets for the label and the training data I am using

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test, lab_train, lab_test = train_test_split(flifghts_features, flights_lable, test_size=0.20, random_state=27121992)
```

Comment: Inputs need to be numbers, not text.  You're going to need to encode the data properly first.

Comment: You cannot train a model on categories as strings. You can refer [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-prepare-categorical-data-for-deep-learning-in-python/) tutorial on how to encode categorical data. Thanks!